# WebView is not clearing self after work

Tags: ios, swift, memory-management, uiwebview

For example I have two `UIViewControllers` (first is presenting second by `segue` in `storyboard`).

Second controller has a `UIWebView` and is loading some default request in `viewDidLoad` method

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        NSURLCache.sharedURLCache().removeAllCachedResponses()
        if let url = NSURL(string: "http://www.ilaks.no/setter-ut-rensefisken-for-sent/?utm_source=rss&utm_medium=rss&utm_campaign=setter-ut-rensefisken-for-sent") {
            webView.loadRequest(NSURLRequest(URL: url, cachePolicy: .ReturnCacheDataElseLoad, timeoutInterval: 30))
        }
    }
```

But each time you are presenting view controller, memory use is increasing. Do somebody know what am I doing wrong?

[Sample project](https://github.com/VasylKhmil/SampleProject)

Run app:
[image]

Present second view controller and wait until `UIWebView` load request:
[image]

Dismiss controller in not clearing any memory, and after second presenting and  you will see:
[image]

So each presenting is requesting some extra memory, but dismissing is not clearing any requested memory

Comment: I suggest you to use [Xcode Instruments](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AnalysisTools/Reference/Instruments_User_Reference/AllocationsInstrument/AllocationsInstrument.html). Then you can simple find if you second view controller gets a release and check if some other live object will be deallocated after created.

Comment: @MatrosovAlexander Already checked. Controller is removing after dismissing, but there is some WebCore processes that live after that

Comment: hm really strange. did you test it on device. or just for test can you set nil in dealloc for nsurlrequest and for uiwebivew.